# NodeJS connect-redis with nodejitsu URI

Tags: node.js, redis

I create a Redis db on nodejitsu and got a full URI such as:

```
 nodejitsu:nodejitsudb11158161232.redis.irstack.com:f327c9sj29sj26e80b8e975fbebb4@nodejitsudb3058169sj32.redis.irstack.com
```

Connect-redis wants a host, port, etc... Anyone know of an easy way I can just pass it this string? Didn't seem to work when setting the host to that - mongodb seems to work fine with this schema.

Answer (score 1):

Use `url.parse` http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html to parse that url into its parts such as host, port, etc....

Comment: It's unable to parse this into the pieces I need without me splitting it manually

Answer (score 0):

So diving in the source it looks like it's unable to parse a dsn string. url.parse doesn't return the necessary info so it has to be broken down further.

The full dsn has the redis:// protocol as well - it must be there for this to work. Because my local redis dsn string doesn't have a password/user there is a check for that in case it's missing:

```
var redisUrl = 'redis://nodejitsu:nodejitsudb3051531232.redis.irstack.com:fd470c971946e8der75fbebb4@nodejitsudb305813frt232.redis.irstack.com:6379';

var redis = url.parse(redisUrl);

app.use(express.session({
  secret: settings.sessionSecret,
  store: new RedisStore({host: redis.hostname, port: redis.port, pass: redis.auth ? redis.auth.substring(redis.auth.indexOf(':') + 1): null})
}));
```